# Browser's backbutton trouble when using ajax calls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a list with search results that is fetched through ajax (to be precise: the microsoft updatepanel). The problem is that I cannot use the backbutton of any webbrowser to navigate back to previous lists that I fetched through ajax. Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make all the ajax calls update the window.location.hash.

```
function getAjaxResource(id) {
  // some ajax stuff
  window.location.hash = 'resource=' + id;
}
```

Then you need to add a watcher to the hash with javascript's setInterval function.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
window.setInterval(function () {
  if (window.location.hash != hash) {
    hash = window.location.hash;
    getAjaxResource(hash.replace('resource=',''));
  }
},100);
```

The hash changes every time the user clicks back/forward and the watcher will pick that change up.

Comment: This won't automatically work with asp.net updatepanels, because they post form data to get the right data for the updatepanel content. If you press the browsers back or forward button it does not know the correct form data of that page-state anymore, so it won't know what to display.

Answer (score 0):

add something to url, like `page.html#state1`, `page.html#state2` etc. It's a common practice

Comment: Hi semyon, thank you for your answer bu I cant do that. Update panel uses POST to get new data.

Comment: @Erwin - you set the hash # in javascript when you make your ajax request